# Fill a node with all elements of array

Tags: jquery, xml, arrays, json

Here I am again!

Well, i have an Array that fills a JSON structure, and i have to fill an XML based on that array structure, how can I do that?

My array contains many data correctly separed as JSON sintax and i need to write into an specific node!

For example I have the following XML

```
<NEIGHBOR>
<TEST>
<HOUSES></HOUSES>
</TEST>
</NEIGHBOR>
```

and the following JSON, that fills an Array:

```
TEST1:$("#TEST1").val(),
TEST2:$("#TEST2").val(),
TEST3:$("#TEST3").val(),
...
```

and I must put all that fields (that filled the array) inside the `<HOUSES>` tag on XML!

How can I do that?

I tried the appendChild() but no success, once i dont know how to locate the `<HOUSES>` tag and then fill it with all the array elements!

Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

```
var xml = '<NEIGHBOR><TEST><HOUSES></HOUSES></TEST></NEIGHBOR>';
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml )
$xml = $( xmlDoc )
$houses = $xml.find('HOUSES');
$houses.append('<HOUSE>' + $("#TEST1").val() + '</HOUSE>');
```

without much to go on.. this is all I can suggest...
most of this code is taken directly off of jquery's [.parseXML() page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)

Comment: Hi! It didn't work! I already have an existing XML, but i need to complete it with the JSON information!

In that case, i must fill the `<TEST>` node in that existing XML (specifically the `<HOUSE>` tag) with the data from array, even if I have to repeat it(create the `<HOUSE>` childs based on each TEST i have) 100 times, it must be repeated for each `<TEST>` I have.